# Android notifyDataSetChanged from a custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

So my app uses a local SQLite db through a contentProvider
In it's mainActivity I have a listView displaying the contents of a table from the above DB.

I use a custom adapter to display the listview. Each item has a button in it's (custom) layout, that when pressed, shows a custom dialog that inserts a new record in that table, then the dialog gets dismissed.
In order to achieve this behavior, I placed the button click handler inside the customAdapter.
I would like to be able to refresh the listView after the inserting is done (so when dialog is dismissed)

How can I achieve this?
I should probably need to call notifyDataSetChanged somehow from inside the custom Adapter but I can't.

In short, my custom adapter looks like this:

```
public class DisplayStuffAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> id;
    private ArrayList<String> iduser;
    private ArrayList<String> product;


    public DisplayStuffAdapter(Context c){
        this.mContext = c;
    }

    public DisplayStuffAdapter(Context c,  ArrayList<String> id, ArrayList<String> userid, ArrayList<String> product) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.id = id;
        this.userid = userid;
        this.product = product;
    }

 public int getCount() {
        return id.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView txt_id;
        TextView txt_userid;
        TextView txt_prod;
    }


  public View getView(int pos, View child, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder mHolder;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        if (child == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.myitem, null);
            mHolder = new Holder();
            mHolder.txt_id = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tv_MkId);
            mHolder.txt_userid = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tv_MkUserId);
            mHolder.txt_prod = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tv_MkProduct);
            child.setTag(mHolder);
        } else {
            mHolder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }
        mHolder.txt_id.setText(id.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_userid.setText(userid.get(pos));
        mHolder.txt_prod.setText(product.get(pos));

     Button bt = (Button) child.findViewById(R.id.itemButton);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
              final View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.bid_dialog, null);
              AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
              alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Input data")
                 .setIcon(R.drawable.add_red_24)
                 .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                                }
                            })
                 .setPositiveButton("Add new record", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                 values.put(MyProvider.TCOL_ID, myid);
                 values.put(MyProvider.TCOL_OTHERID, Integer.toString(getActiveUserId()));
                 Uri uri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI_TABLE, values);
                 values = new ContentValues();
                 dialogInterface.dismiss();
                      }
                    }
                  }
               });

                // create alert dialog
                final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
                alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
....
        }
    });
....
```

I remove some parts from the code to make it more readable.
Now, in my MainActivity, I set the adapter like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> userid = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> product = new ArrayList<String>();
 ...
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fillListView();
    }
 ...

 private void fillListView(){
        id.clear();
        userid.clear();
        product.clear();

        String[] col = {MyProvider.TCOL_ID_ID, MyProvider.TCOL_USERID, MyProvider.TCOL_PROD};
        String where = "done = 1";
        Cursor mCursor =  MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI_TABLE, col, where, null, MyProvider.TCOL_DATE + " desc");
        if (mCursor != null) {
            if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    id.add(Integer.toString(mCursor.getInt(0)));
                    userid.add(Integer.toString(mCursor.getInt(1)));
                    product.add(mCursor.getString(2));
                } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }

        DisplayStuffAdapter disadpt = new DisplayStuffAdapter(MainActivity.this,id,userid,product);
        disadpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistView);
        lv.setAdapter(disadpt);
    }
```

So this all works great, except that when I add a new record to the table using the customdialog described above... the dialog closes, and the listview remains unchanged.

How can I refresh the listView?

Comment: why you cant do call to notifyDataSetChanged in DisplayStuffAdapter? Even in anonyoums class you can do it like this : DisplayStuffAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: Lester: I tried that already, but the listview does not get refreshed

Comment: Mark, your solution sounds interesting, however, I am kind of new to this, so I would rather see some code than theory. Code allways makes me understand better an idea

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DisplayStuffAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> id;
    private ArrayList<String> iduser;
    private ArrayList<String> product;

    public DisplayStuffAdapter(Context c){
        this.mContext = c;
    }

    public void loadData(){
        id.clear();
        userid.clear();
        product.clear();

        String[] col = {MyProvider.TCOL_ID_ID, MyProvider.TCOL_USERID, MyProvider.TCOL_PROD};
        String where = "done = 1";
        Cursor mCursor =  MainActivity.this.getContentResolver().query(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI_TABLE, col, where, null, MyProvider.TCOL_DATE + " desc");
        if (mCursor != null) {
            if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    id.add(Integer.toString(mCursor.getInt(0)));
                    userid.add(Integer.toString(mCursor.getInt(1)));
                    product.add(mCursor.getString(2));
                } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
...
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private DisplayStuffAdapter disadpt = null;

    ContentObserver displayStuffObserver = new ContentObserver(new Handler()){  
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            if(disadpt != null) {
                disadpt.loadData();
            }
        }       
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        disadpt = new DisplayStuffAdapter(this);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistView);
        lv.setAdapter(disadpt);
        disadpt.loadData();
           getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MyProvider.CONTENT_URI_TABLE,true, displayStuffObserver);
    }
}
```

Do not forget to unregister your content observer

Comment: It would be so simple... but nothing changes. I also placed the notifyDatasetChanged after the setAdapter, same result... the listView is not refreshing

Comment: Sorry... I've completely missed the fact that fillListView() is called in onCreate. You have to re-query content resolver every time you modify or insert record in content provider. Please move fillListView() in DisplayStuffAdapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() after lists are loaded from content resolver. Also, in onClick, after record is inserted, call fillListView().

Comment: Alternative way would be the one suggested above by Mimmo Grottoli. Use ContentObserver and call fillListView() and notifyDataSetChanged() in onChange()

Comment: yfranz , could you please ellaborate loadData() method, based on my DisplayStuffAdapter in the question? Your solution seems very easy to follow for me. I just want to fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you're querying data from a DB, you should use `ContentProvider` and `CursorLoader`. You can configure your content provider to automatically notify loaders when some data changes, using ContentResolver `notifyChange()` method. Place the call to this method in your ContentProvider implementation (for example after the insert). This is an example of adapter you can use (but you can use SimpleCursorAdapter providing a view binder too).

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    super(context, c, flags);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    if(cursor.getPosition()%2==1) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.background_odd));
    }
    else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.background_even));
    }
    TextView content = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.row_content);
    content.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Table.CONTENT)));
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
}

}
```

Comment: For ContentProvider, look inside samples/.../connectivity/BasicSyncAdapter/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/basicsyncadapter/provider/FeedProvider.java. Note that at the end of every method that change some data there is a call to notifyChange(). In this way, if you have a loader properly configured, the loader will automatically reload data (the onLoadFinished is called again) and you can replace data inside your adapter or create a new one.

Comment: Your solution is generic, I would need solution closer to my approach. The tutorial works with SimpleCursorAdapter not a custom one. I am already using a ContentProvider (as I explained in the question). I am interested in how do I adapt using a Loader with my custom BaseAdapter in order to be able to refresh my ListView

Comment: What solution do you mean? Your answer just describes what I already do, except for the CursorLoader. Also your answer is a generic suggestion, not a solution. I would love to see "your solution" (with some code). It would probably work, since mine (described with code) does not. I do the DB querying on the main thread because I do not deal with a large table, so it's pointless to complicate my code with that at this point.

Comment: As explained in the question, my listView is a bit more complex (has a button in the layout of the each item of the listview, that responds to the users click, uses a custom layout for the item, uses a custom adapter for the listView). Sure... the simple solution would be to NOT have all these, but then I would not have the desired functionality and design

Comment: If you can tell me how can I access the layout using the SimpleCursorAdapter in order to make a TextView visible or not, then how to set the clickListener for the button in that layout, and how to load images in a thumbnail (in the layout) based on the pos of the cursor in the table... then I would gladly try and switch to SimpleCursorAdapter. Ohterwise... I will use a workaround because I am under a lot of pressure to finish this project and I have no time to research documentation and try/fail stuff

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not getting why you are sending three different arraylists to the adapter. You can simply make a modal class having all the fields that you require in your adapter. Considering your current scenario it will be something like this

```
public class ModalClass {

private String id = "";
private String userId = "";
private String product = "";

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(String product) {
    this.product = product;
}
}
```

So this is your modal class with getters and setters. Now all you have to do is you have to make an ArrayList of this modal class like this

```
List<ModalClass> modalClassList=new ArrayList<ModalClass>();
```

and you have to set all the data that you want to display in your list in this arraylist by making use of modal class setter functions. Like this

```
  if (mCursor != null) {
        if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                  ModalClass modalClass=new ModalClass();
                  modalClass.setId(Integer.toString(mCursor.getInt(0)));
                  modalClass.setUserId(Integer.toString(mCursor.getInt(1)));
                  modalClass.setProduct(mCursor.getString(2));
                  modalClassList.add(modalClass);
            } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

and now you have your arraylist ready, so you can set it to your listview like this

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylistView);
DisplayStuffAdapter disadpt = new DisplayStuffAdapter(MainActivity.this,modalClassList); 
lv.setAdapter(disadpt);
```

And accordingly you have to modify your adapter constructor which i think you can do by your own.

Also how to set values in your adapter, you can make use of your modal class getter methods like this.

```
    ModalClass modalClass=modalClassList.get(pos);
    mHolder.txt_id.setText(modalClass.getId());
    mHolder.txt_userid.setText(modalClass.getUserId());
    mHolder.txt_prod.setText(modalClass.getProduct());
```

Now when you want to insert a new row in your adapter, you have to simply create an object of ModalClass and set all the new values in that like we have done in our MainActivity class and then finally add that to your modalClassList followed by notifyDataSetChanged();

```
    ModalClass modalClass=new ModalClass();
    modalClass.setId(yourNewInsertedRowId);
    modalClass.setUserId(yourNewInsertedRowUserId);
    modalClass.setProduct(yourNewInsertedRowProduct);
    modalClassList.add(modalClass);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And this time your list will be notify for sure. Cheers :)